# Cohen's d for 2x2 anova interaction

Tags: anova, interaction, references, cohens-d

I would like to calculate Cohen's d for 2x2 ANOVA interaction (nationality: Germany, France; gender: male, female).

Someone asked similar question earlier ([Cohen's d for 2x2 interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/cohens-d-for-2x2-interaction)), and got an advise to calculate Cohen's d using (a1 - b1) - (a2 - b2) as a numerator and the square root of the MSE from the ANOVA as a denominator.

Could someone please tell me a reference, where I could find more information how to calculate Cohen's d using this formula? I really cannot find any. What would a1, a2, b1 and b2 be in my case?

Comment: You'd have to actually add details about your case for anyone to answer the second part of your question. There's no such thing as a reference for your first part since that's just the trivial mathematical equation for your interaction effect. To be more clear, `a` and `b` are the variables and the numbers are levels of the variables.

Comment: Now that @John has edited his answer at the possible duplicate to clarify what the `a1` etc refer to, I can't see anything in this question which isn't answered there.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I see that I missed a key part of the question, which is your confusion about what a1, a2, b1, and b2 actually are. These refer to the 4 cell means in the 2x2 design. Imagine that subjects get randomly assigned twice: first to either condition a or condition b, and then to either condition 1 or condition 2. So each subjects ends up in either group a1, a2, b1, or b2. In what I wrote below, I use these labels as shorthand to refer to the *group means* rather than the groups themselves (as in the previous advice you received).

Actually I think it is more appropriate to use
$$
d=\frac{(a1-b1)-(a2-b2)}{2\sigma}
$$
rather than the definition you mentioned. I covered this on my blog a few months back ([LINK](https://web.archive.org/web/20231001081118/http://jakewestfall.org/blog/index.php/2015/05/27/follow-up-what-about-uris-2n-rule/)) but I'll cover the basic argument again here.

If we take your numerator and distribute the implicit $-1$, we see that it equals
$$
a1-b1-a2+b2=(+1)a1 + (-1)a2 + (-1)b1 + (+1)b2.
$$
The key here is to realize that this is still a comparison between two group means, just like in the classical definition of Cohen's d. We are comparing the a1 and b2 groups (which have coefficients of +1 in the above sum) against the a2 and b1 groups (which have coefficients of -1). So the two relevant means to use in computing d are the mean of the a1 and b2 means, $\mu_1=\frac{a1+b2}{2}$, and the mean of the a2 and b1 means, $\mu_2=\frac{a2+b1}{2}$. This gives us
$$
d=\frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma}=\frac{\frac{a1+b2}{2}-\frac{a2+b1}{2}}{\sigma}=\frac{(a1-b1)-(a2-b2)}{2\sigma}.
$$
I think that this is the most natural extension of the classical Cohen's d to a 2x2 interaction effect.

If you're not convinced yet, see my blog comment ([HERE](https://web.archive.org/web/20231001081118/http://jakewestfall.org/blog/index.php/2015/05/27/follow-up-what-about-uris-2n-rule/#comment-24)) for some further arguments for why this should be preferred over the effect size definition that you mentioned.